# how do I stick the scrollbars of ScrollViewer to top in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, scrollviewer

I have an Itemscontrol in my xaml inside a ScrollViewer.

> ```
>    <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0">
>         <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsStackPanel">
>             <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
>                 <DataTemplate>
>                     <controls:UserItem Margin="0, 5, 0, 3"></controls:UserItem>
>                 </DataTemplate>
>             </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
>         </ItemsControl>
>     </ScrollViewer>
> ```

and here is the list I am assigning to ItemsControl,

> this.itemsStackPanel.ItemsSource = usersList;

now whenever new items are added in usersList, the UI updates and the scrollbar of ScrollViewer reaches at bottom. how do I stick it to top??

**--EDIT--**
one more issue I found, is that when ever the scrollviewer is resized horizontally, the scrollbars reach at bottom. how to keep the scrollbars on top while resizing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to call

```
scrollView.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
```

[MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset%28VS.95%29.aspx)

However, this might just cause the list to scroll to the bottom and then the top again - not what you want.

Comment: no, it does not help, the scrollbars are still stuck to bottom